TMP102 schematic
I am trying to make a custom thermometer pcb and I want to use an atmega328 and a TMP102 thermometer. I am an absolute noob and I was wondering if I have to copy all of those components seen in the schematic over to my own pcb or if some of those parts are expendable.
Question: Do I need all of those resistors and capacitors in the schematics or can I use only the IC. (What are the essential components)
Thank you for any help :)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes they all are essential for proper operation and proper usage of the chip.
Unless some exceptional circumstances apply, which is unknown.
You should be reading the data sheet of the chip how to use it, not looking at a random instance of using that chip and working backwards of guessing how to use it based on one single example.

Thanks for the answer. That is an official schematic from SparkFun. I don't really know how to read datasheets and when I read them I don't really understand them

so should I add all of them to my custom pcb

@LMJ Like I said, it depends how you are going to use that chip. If you don't need changeable address, you can tie the address pin low or high directly. If your MCU already has pull-ups on I2C or you want to use internal pull-ups (which may work but I definitely do not recommend it), you can leave them off. If you don't need the alert pin, you can maybe tie it to ground. If you already have a bypass cap within few millimeters of the chip, you can omit it too. Otherwise, just draw them all and worry about not populating them if you don't need them, it's better than not drawing them and needing.

Is there any way of simulating a circuit like that before I print it ? Or is there a community that can like look over it for me and point out any obvious flaws ?

@LMJ There are many ways of simulating a circuit. Unfortunately, if you were to simulate the effect of e.g. a capacitor that is an inch away or a foot away from a chip that requies a capacitor, you need to simulate the inch or foot of wires with a model for the wire, so it isn't useful. This is so simple circuit, just draw the components like in your example or read the datasheet which has a minimal example of how to get it to work. Many people ask schematic review questions here, but often, they are too open-ended and any and all answers can be correct, so often they are poor questions.
